# How to extract specific variables from a string python?

Tags: python

I have a string like `"A:22.0 /4.03 B:15.05 /3.0 C:120.15 /12.4"` (with the spaces).

---

I want to extract the numbers and to store them intro variables with specific names. For the example, i want to have the variable `A1 = 22.0`, `A2 = 4.03`, `B1 = 15.05`, `B2 = 3.0`, `C1 = 120.15`, `C2 = 12.4` 
The variables in the string might not be in this order, but there will always be groups of: 
 `(variable name):(value1) /(value2)` in this order.

Any help or idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Define a grammar, then write a parser, then use that parser to parse your strings - simple! 

(Just kidding, that's quite a task: try creating a regex to get each group separately and then try to parse each group)

Comment: Well, I am just going to give you a hint to get you started. Parse the string (either split or regular expressions) and store the key value pairs it into a dictionary. You never did specify about potential edge cases. What if you see two A's in the string?

Comment: How about storing them in a dictionary, like `nums = {'A':[22, 4.03], 'B':[15.05, 3], 'C':[120.15. 12.4]}`? Would a result like that work for you? Then you could access the values like `nums['B'][1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a million ways to do this.  Regular expressions are great and can be helpful for missing values and other edge cases.  Assuming your data is never missing a value or in any other format a simple string replacement and split can do the job.

You'll find it difficult name variables based on values from a string (A1, A2, etc).  It's better to use a dictionary to store this type of data.

The complex part of this is the construction of the dictionary, which in this case is counting from 0 to the length of items in the split list, by 3s, and using those numbers to create the key:value pairs of the dictionary.

Original String

```
x = "A:22.0 /4.03 B:15.05 /3.0, C:120.15 /12.4"
```

Replace special characters w/space and split on spaces (will remove extra whitespace)

```
b = x.replace(':',' ').replace('/',' ').split()
```

Gives you

```
['A', '22.0', '4.03', 'B', '15.05', '3.0,', 'C', '120.15', '12.4']
```

Construct a dictionary from your data

```
output = {b[x]:[b[x+1],b[x+2]] for x in range(0,len(b),3)}
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['22.0', '4.03'], 'B': ['15.05', '3.0,'], 'C': ['120.15', '12.4']}
```

Then access the data as such:

```
output['A'][0]
22.0
output['A'][1]
4.03
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract them, you should use Regex: here is the documentation: [RegEx (Python)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

But I recommend you to take a look at dictionaries. It will provide a control of keys and values, it looks what you need. Here is an example:

```
variableName = {
        "A1":22.0,
        "A2":4.03
    }
```

Here is the link to a good tutorial of how to use this: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/

Comment: The idea with the dictionaries should help me with the job, thank you!